# PHPUnit - Can I run tests for a lower version of PHP?

Tags: php, phpunit, version, requirements

As explained [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.testsuites) I can run a test for if the PHP version is at least 5.3.0.

But if I want to run tests for a PHP version lower then 5.3.0?

I write this:

```
<file phpVersion="5.3.0" phpVersionOperator="<=">./tests/unit/test-file.php</file>
```

But I receive this error

```
Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
```

How could I do it?

Comment: phpVersion doesn't tell PHPUnit to "fake" a different PHP version to what you've got. It just sets the required minimum PHP version so if your version doesn't match that requirement the tests will (possibly) not take place.

Comment: lower the version instead. Alternatively, use `@requires` on your test

Comment: which version of phpunit are you using?

Comment: @gordon how? I didn't see any way to add operator on `@requires` annotation
@matteo PHPUnit 4.8.27

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In accordion with the doc of the [version_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) function:

> The possible operators are: <, lt, <=, le, >, gt, >=, ge, ==, =, eq,
>   !=, <>, ne respectively.

That is used in the phpunit core [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.5/src/Util/Configuration.php#L942), you can simply specify `lt` as value. As example:

```
<file phpVersion="5.3.0" phpVersionOperator="lt">./tests/unit/test-file.php</file>
```

Hope this help

**NOTE:**

If the files is also included in another directive of the test suite it will be however executed, as example in this situation:

```
<testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
    <directory>tests</directory>  <!-- This line execute the test -->
    <file phpVersion="5.3.0" phpVersionOperator="<=">./tests/unit/test-file.php</file>
</testsuite>
```

So be selective in the test suite definition.

Comment: Link https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.5/src/Util/Configuration.php#L942 is broken. But the trick of setting `lt` works!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape < inside the attribute:

```
<file phpVersion="5.3.0" phpVersionOperator="&lt;=">./tests/unit/test-file.php</file>
```

Comment: The question that arises me is why do we have to escape `<=` but don't `>=`? Curious, isn't it?